# Why do we have the [tag:coding] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

We have a tag for [coding](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding). But the description for the tag says it shouldn't be used and that it should be eliminated.

It seems that either we should actually eliminate the tag; or else we should agree that the tag is useful and give it a helpful description.

Comment: I think I wrote that wiki excerpt. The tag should be eliminated by retagging some Qs to [categorical-encoding] and by removing it from some Qs altogether. It still exists because nobody so far did the work of actually going through the Qs and retagging them.

Comment: @amoeba I've completed re-tagging all of these questions.

Comment: Related discussion: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5020/28666.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that [at one point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/312194/revisions) it was supposed to be about the coding of categorical variables.  Note that we now have [categorical-encoding](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/categorical-encoding).  This tag should just be burninated.

Comment: (+1) This sounds like a good idea to me. But just to give potential dissenters the chance to make their case, I'll hold off on marking this as "answered" for a few days.

Comment: @Sycorax Please don't mark this as answered as long as the tag still exists.

Comment: @gung I've completed re-tagging all of the [tag:coding] questions. The tag can be burninated.

Comment: @Sycorax, it will disappear naturally after 24 hours if it isn't on any threads.

Comment: I don’t think that will burn the tag though. We don’t want people to re-make the coding tag in the future, do we?

Comment: @Sycorax, I can contact the community team & ask them to blacklist the tag, but I can't do it myself. Whether they'll do it depends on how they feel about it. '[Burninating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/187282)' mostly just means deleting, which we (you) have done.

Comment: I don't think that blacklisting is necessary.

Comment: @amoeba, blacklisting is the only way to ensure people can't remake the tag. FWIW, I've already contacted the community team; I suppose I could contact them again to cancel, but I'm disinclined to do so.

Comment: I see! There is certainly no problem with blacklisting. It's just that I was under impression that our community has not blacklisted any tag in the last 5+ years (I think some tags might have been blacklisted in the early days of CV), so I assumed this is perceived (by mods) as a major hassle. If you are willing to initiate the blacklisting process whenever it seems appropriate, I am only happy.

Comment: @amoeba, well, Sycorax asked me to. The SE community mods might get sick of me if I start emailing them blacklist requests every week, but this one seemed reasonable.

Comment: Now that we are discussing contacting SE mods, @gung, what do you think about contacting SE mods to burninate some tags? As in remove them from all threads by admin super-powers? I think we had some worthy candidates, we could try to make a list if that is something you would want to do in principle.

Comment: I'd have to go back & look into it. I thought the answer was that *we* need to remove them from all threads.